# How to add class in inline styling for specific attribute for each in php?

Tags: php, html

I am creating a plugin. Settings will be saved in variable when user will enter any value. Here is code:

```
<div class="content" style="text-align: <?php echo $textalign; ?>;">
    <?php echo $content; ?>
</div>
```

`$content` is wp page editor and `$textalign` is `text-align` (left, center, right) style.

I want to add an option of `text-align` for `ul>li` (if user add item list in page editor). If I write it in styling tag `.content ul li {text-align: <?php echo $textalign; ?>;}` then it will be apply. But I want to add it in inline style so it apply different for each php code for different settings.
It does't work directly `style="text-align: <?php echo $textalign; ?>;"` but it work writing like this `.content ul li {text-align: center;}`. So how I can add class using inline styling for specific attribute?

See the screenshot:

[image: http://prntscr.com/cbzqtu]

Comment: `how i can add inline style adding class` ? You want to add class or inline style? It is not clear what is your question. Anyway, you'd have better to set all style using classes and just add specific class for each element

Answer (score 0):

This you have to achieve with js. You cannot write such inline rule.

```
$(document).ready({
  $('.content').find('ul li').css({textalign:<?php echo $textalign; ?>})
})
```